# polymorphic laravel morphTo?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I want to create a somewhat polymorphic laravel morphTo.

I want to create multiple 'dimension' polymorphic properties but don't see a need to create four separate (identical) tables for their values (width, length, height, weight).

The problem is, I just stumbled upon how it creates the linking and I'm not quite sure how to specify the type of dimension.

I was looking at creating an abstract 'Dimension' model then wrapping it with inherited 'Width', 'Length', 'Height' and 'Weight' models that would set the 'axis' attribute before calling the parent __constructor($attributes)

I thought I found the solution but it does not seem to be working. I created a 'widthable' method in my Width() class (inherited from DimensionAbstract) and gave it the name and id fields 'dimensionable_name', 'dimensionable_id' respectively. e.g.:

```
public function widthable()
{
    return $this->morphTo(__FUNCTION__, 'dimensionable_type', 'dimensionable_id');
}
```

But it complains that widthable_id column not found.  Is there some way to key a morphOne (or a pseudo variant of same) hinging on one of the properties of the morphed class? (In my case, I use an enum for 'axis' that can include 'width', 'length', 'height' or 'weight' - then I set that attribute in the constructor)
I was trying to do similar things in each of the other inherited classes for Length, Height and Weight.

Answer (score 0):

So as far as I can understand you have a table called dimensions and you want to use id dynamically.
Why aren't you creating a model called **Dimension**, than create other separate models for **Width**, **Length**, **Height** and **Weight** which will extend that **Dimension** model, and on every model that extends **Dimension** use a global scope where you filter on **axis** for ex. `->where('axis', 'width')`, and make a function in each Model such as `setAxisAttribute()` which sets axis to corresponding value based on model ex:

```
public function setAxisAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['axis'] = 'width';
}
```

Or maybe I didn't understand you correctly.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I also needed to define the type and key on the morphOne side. (the documentation wasn't clear on that). But now that leads me to another question. My functions for each type are very similar. And in some cases they seem to rely on the function name for some properties. I'm overriding those two now, but I need to check if any other methods use the function name. I'd prefer to use a magic method for those.

Answer (score 0):

After deep tracing the code, I finally figured out what I needed (which was something I half expected). To use the different keys, I also needed to define them on the morphOne side as well as the inverse morphTo.  Then find the one that matched when pulling the result of what was actually a morph one from many (the documentation was not clear on that).  e.g.:

```
public function width()
{
    return $this->morphOne(Height::class, __FUNCTION__.'able', 'dimensionable_type', 'dimensionable_id')->where('axis', __FUNCTION__);
}
```

I also have a similar (actual) morphOne for pricing information. Currently it's still basic enough it could technically be supported by the same framework, but I want to add additional method-behaviors to pricing such as having the value represent a percentage that can be used as a modifier on the total price for sub-component parts. (e.g. select option 'a' and get 10% off)

I'm now thinking that for these basic key/value/unit properties, I can wrap them in a single 'dimensions' class to act as a go between then use a magic method for handling the morphOne (technically many-to-one) relations.